# How to debug web worker script under electron?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, electron, web-worker

I'm writing a debugger tool using Electron (I'm creating my own UI, so I don't use the built-in DevTools).

I'm using [`win.webContents.debugger`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/debugger.md) to access the debugger instance and I can control my renderer.

The problem is when the renderer creates a web worker:

`new Worker('script.js');`

I don't receive any debugger related events to it nor can I access it (I can access it when I use DevTools, but I not using the debugger instance).

How can I access and control my web worker with the debugger instance?

EDIT: I've setup a demo project to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/giladno/electron-quick-start